# PHP/MySQL matching cell based on column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks like this.

```
 x  2  3  4  5
 4  8 12 16 20
 5 10 15 20 25
 6 12 18 24 30
 7 14 21 28 35
```

When an end user plugs in one value I want to match the x variable to the values in the x column and the other variable to the numerical column names.

So how would I go about writing an SQL query that does this?

```
SELECT * FROM times_tables WHERE x=4 and COLUMN_NAME=4;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I hate to ask but why are you doing it this way?

Comment: **@NullRef**, I think it will be easier to do this, if `times_tables` were a many-to-many association table. I recommend OP to consider "table reorganization" as an option.

Comment: @CORRUPT or even a 3 column table with X Y and PRODUCT would be easier to deal with.

Comment: It's hard to reorganise when there are a lot of rows and columns. This was the only way I could think of doing it. Do any of you guys know how to reorganise table data efficiently?

Comment: at present, whatever data you have is organized :)

Comment: **@user2288983**, backup `times_tables` to file. Drop `times_table`. Create new one. Supply data from backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `4`
FROM
    (SELECT
        4 as `x`, 8 as `2`, 12 as `3`, 16 as `4`, 20 as `5`
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, 12, 18, 24, 30
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 7, 14, 21, 28, 35) `times_tables`
WHERE
    `x` = 4
```

Output:

```
4
---
16
```

So in your case query might be something like this:

```
SELECT `{$col}` FROM `times_tables` WHERE `x` = {$row};
```

**UPD:**

Might be done with pure SQL:

```
SET @r = 4; -- row
SET @c = 5; -- col

SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT `', @c ,'` FROM `times_tables` WHERE `x` = ', @r);

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**P.S.:** You may wrap SQL into a stored procedure for better protection.

Comment: My table has like 300 entries per column so is there another way of doing it?

Comment: It isn`t a "square" table ?

Comment: Doesn`t matter. It should be a dynamic query. I fixed `$col` and `$row` variables to be different, but I see no other way. **@Arun Killu**, thanx though.